# Typescript conditional generic property inference

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics, type-inference

I have a react component and want to make it bullet proof in terms of props.

My question is, can typescript actually infer this or did I do something wrong.
Simplified version:

```
type DatePickerProps<Clearable extends boolean = false> = {
    clearable:Clearable
    value: DatePickerValue<Clearable>
    onChange: (value:DatePickerValue<Clearable>) => void
}

type DatePickerValue<Clearable extends boolean> = Clearable extends true ? Date | undefined : Date

function DatePicker<Clearable extends boolean = false>({clearable,value,onChange}:DatePickerProps<Clearable>){
    onChange(value)
    if(clearable === true)
        onChange(undefined)

}
```

Right now it's crying because of undefined and I'm aware that I can do something like this `undefined as DatePickerValue<Clearable>` to shut typescript up, but I don't want to shut up typescript.

As clearable is true in this case, it should be possible to set undefined.

To play around, here is the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAFAlgYwNYQE5OwezAGcAeAYQBsI5s4AjKqCAD0QDsATIqO-fKuGygBeKADM4FIhAB8IqAG8AsACgo6qGgG0GEAFxRK1HVVUaoAN0kBXfbATJ0WbADUbEctvpUZZjfjYyAAtBAHM7AAorClsDeERUTBw3GI8jGm9ZAEoROQt8FA5VAF9VVVBIewSnZPdPY0ymVghObl5+ajY5UXSTaBZ2LihgbFsoAH4q6AAfKGtOCDEUNggOKDiHMpUxebRgFACpxOd6jN0mwba+ASFRCSlZCIVNL10AGkt3D4DgsOhijbVJK4AjEU59GQ5ZRqfyBEJscJRdxZPzqFBiKARLQNc7CPHDUYQFEw8zqH7wxHzDiLZarYklVRAA)

Comment: Hmm, I don't get your logic.  Doesn't `Clearable extends true ? Date : Date | undefined` imply that you get `Date` and not `Date | undefined` if `Clearable` is `true`?  What's going on here?  Am I misreading it?  (If there is a mistake, fixing that isn't going to suddenly make the compiler happy, but it might possibly stop people who want to help from being caught up in implementation details.)

Comment: Assuming I understand correctly, the compiler is never going to be able to understand generic conditional types the way you are hoping for; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) (which talks about return types but the issue is the same).  You'll need to refactor somewhere; personally I'd suggest switching to a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4Y1W).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz there was still hope for me, but my fear has thus come true. Sad life with typescript.  I wished for going around discriminated union. I prefer to continue with swift now ;). You can post this as answer, I will definitely accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jcalz I was actually so sure, that it works, because of Material-UI doing this:
[AutoComplete Value Type](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/a563a60219f7f6519fb0f34f6d8e3bf0974e6495/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.d.ts#L23-L27)

Turns out it is just a definition file :D

Comment: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIAiBDcsAKBLAxga1gE7oED20AzgDwDCANrMgcgEb3ywAeaAdgCbnxmJEvWTd4AXngAzZLXKwAfJPgBvUPE3xsopq1gAueHQZ76AGg1aAbnICuhpKgw58BAGr3YNXS3qKrTRJuagALMQBzRxp2Llg+ASERBnEpWXklAApbWgcjFDQsPEJPXO9qRQBKSWVrEkxeUABfUAgYBAKXYo8vH1M-BE4efkFhUW5lKRNGAdjhgXACB3gAfic0eAAfeDs+WGlMblheeHznVpBpXexwTGD1rrc+mf05+JGk8ZV0hUVM1XgwTCkVg5m0vn0YJyyyaZ0KrkIxDIVGmZiU1XUIC0gJC4W4UWyXkqgXgmGk8EymHIABUlrBMjp+vpKtUSdigXiopQoHASOTGS9-Jldrx9odjsSsVpYBkccD8d4ebA+eCmUKjgB3B6ZFkk5oXK7cG53cRU2kObIGT4pSoGaykhZ0zHYgiwcB2AjiazNIA) this should work but that's not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the answer from @jcalz

```
type DatePickerProps = {
    clearable?: false
    value: Date
    onChange: (value: Date) => void
} | {
    clearable: true
    value: Date | undefined
    onChange: (value: Date | undefined) => void
}

function DatePicker({ clearable, value, onChange }: DatePickerProps) {
    if (clearable) {
        onChange(value);
        onChange(undefined)
    } else {
        onChange(value);
    }
}
```

To be honest, please fix typescript. If you work with optionals and this kind of types, it's really fun to write multiple ifs in the code, to let typescript know whats going on.